# delete a page from a breadcrumb trail

Tags: breadcrumb

Currently I am working on adding a breadcrumb without a plugin to a site. I found several possibilities on how to do that, but what I specifically want is to take one Page out of the trail.

My current trail is as follows:
home - products - productgroup - productsubgroup - productname

What I want it to become is:
home - productgroup - productsubgroup - productname

Does anyone have experience with this particular challenge?

I'm on the latest WP version and I am using a child theme of Twenty Ten. More info on the breadcrumb I am using: http://www.bloggingtips.com/2009/02/22/create-a-breadcrumb-trail/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the code your used my guess is it would be as simple as adding a `unset($bcarray[0]);` to their code on line 15. Here is the code in it's entirety:

```
function write_breadcrumb() {
  $pid = $post->ID;
  $trail = "<a href='/'>Home</a>";
  if (is_front_page()) :
    // do nothing
  elseif (is_page()) :
    $bcarray = array();
    $pdata = get_post($pid);
    $bcarray[] = " &raquo; ".$pdata->post_title."\n";
    while ($pdata->post_parent) :
      $pdata = get_post($pdata->post_parent);
      $bcarray[] = " &raquo; <a href='".get_permalink($pdata->ID)."'>".$pdata->post_title."</a>\n";
    endwhile;
    $bcarray = array_reverse($bcarray);
    unset($bcarray[0]);
    foreach ($bcarray AS $listitem) :
      $trail .= $listitem;
    endforeach;
  elseif (is_single()) :
    $pdata = get_the_category($pid);
    $data = get_category_parents($pdata[0]->cat_ID, TRUE, ' &raquo; ');
    $trail .= " &raquo; ".substr($data,0,-8);
  endif;
  return $trail;
}
```

-Mike

Comment: Thanks Mike, for both the answer and the speed! What does the 0 mean in your additional line?
update: it works brilliantly, thanks again!

Comment: @Piet: The `[0]` is the first element in the array named `$bcarray` which is also the last item added to the array which was the one you wanted removed. It's that's not clear, ask again. Thanks for the checkmark and upvote.

Comment: ah ok, so if I would have liked to remove any other parent down the line, I could change that number?
Thx for the additional explanation! It's easy to copy and paste and find out it works, it's better to fully understand what's happening and why :)

Comment: @Piet - Sure.  If you really want to find out what works, get a copy of PhpStorm (while it's still $49) and get the debugger set up and then you can know all, just like me. :)